# Counting network hops

Tags: networking

Is there any algorithm that calculates the number of network-hops a computer has to make in order to reach another computer? I tried to google it but nothing matches my query.

Comment: "network related" is not a useful title.  I've edited your post accordingly...

Comment: How about using old-fashioned traceroute <hostname>? (called tracert on Windows)

Answer (score 4):

Try TRACEROUTE or TRACERT on Windows.

Mere 'algorithm' has something to do with TTL on UDP packets (old school) and ICMP ECHO in newer implementations.

Hope you have enough keywords for googling now.